# Help applying Bayes' Law

Tags: probability, bayesian

my problem is the following:

Lets imagine we have a computer with 3 memories (m1, m2, m3).

When data is needed it is searched if m1, if not found in m1, it is searched in m2 and so on.

P(finding data on m1) = P(m1) is unknown, P(m2) = 0.6

Now the question is: What is P(m1) knowing that 76% of the time we do not need to go to m3, we found it in m2.

How can you apply Bayes law here?

If you do P(m1 | m1 v m2), which i believe is, P of finding it in m1 knowing that is either in m1 or in m2,

P(m1 | m1 v m2) = P(m2 v m1 | m1) * P(m2)/P(m1) = 0.76

but then P(m2 v m1 | m1) is 1 since being in m2 or m1 knowing that it is in m1 is trivial, and you get that P(m2)/P(m1) = 0.76 wich means that P(m1) = P(m2)*0.76 = 0.6*0.76 but that is not the correct answer...

What am I doing wrong?

thanks a lot for your time and sorry for my bad explanations, english not my mother tongue :p

Comment: There are ambiguities. (i) could the information be in more than one of the memories? (ii) Does $0.6$ represent the probability that the information is in memory $2$? Or is it the conditional probability that it is in memory $2$ given it is not in memory $1$? On the assumption of independence, I get $m_1=0.4$.

Comment: I'm assuming that instead of "76% of the time we do not need to go to m3, we found it in m2", you really meant "76% of the time we do not need to go to m3, we found it in m2 *or in m1*". Also, what does the problem-source say is the correct answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bayes' law is not needed.

Let $M_i = \text{" the data is in memory } m_i"$.
We're given that
$$\Bbb{P}(M_2) = 0.6$$
and, since the data is *not* in $m_3$ if and only if it is in $m1$ or $m2$, we also have the given value 
$$\Bbb{P}(\overline{M_3}) = \Bbb{P}(M_1 \cup M_2) = 0.76$$
Note also that since the data is in only *one* of the three memories,
$$\Bbb{P}(M_1 \cap M_2) = 0$$

Now by the [principle of inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability), 
$$\Bbb{P}(M_1 \cup M_2) = \Bbb{P}(M_1) + \Bbb{P}(M_2) - \Bbb{P}(M_1 \cap M_2)
$$
which we can now solve for $\Bbb{P}(M_1)$:

$$\Bbb{P}(M_1) = 0.76 - 0.6 = 0.16$$

Comment: ah alright much tanks sir

Comment: You're welcome. Note: this solution assumes that instead of "76% of the time we do not need to go to m3, we found it in m2", you really meant "76% of the time we do not need to go to m3, we found it in m2 *or in m1*". Since this answer has been accepted, I presume that it's the value given by your problem-source.